# Finish() fragment class in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, fragment

Right now i am working with two fragments assume namely **frag_one** and **frag_two**.

If i launch the app at first the **frag_one** will get invoked and it is having one Asynctask class which will be executed on onCreateView().
Later it will list some data in list-view, if i click any item from the list-view it will call the second fragment class say **frag_two**, in this fragment i am showing some data.

Here my problem begins

if i click the device's back button then it is navigating me to the previous fragment ie.,**frag_one** this is what i want actually this is working fine, 
but the asynctask which i am using in **frag_one** is executing again after the back button is pressed.

But i don't want to execute that asynctask again, and i want to show data which is already shown at first launch.

So that have i to finish the **frag_two** or remove the **frag_two**.

Suggestion please

thanks for your precious time!..

Comment: If you Replace `Fragment` in `Fragment Transaction` then `onCreateView(...)` called it again. so that your `AsyncTask` is call again. So better to `Attach` and `Detach` your `Fragment`.

Comment: in your case fragment will recreate after back press, it is correct; when you are loading data from web API, you have stored it in array List or db?? just check array List size or db size to load data again or not.

Comment: @SimplePlan do you have any example for your suggestion,so far i've searched but they are not making me clear..can you please make me clear by giving some samples

Comment: @prabu Take a look on this best example ever [creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/creating-navigation-tabs-using-tabhost-and-fragments-in-android/)